# Extract date ranges from OCR extracts

Tags: python, regex

My regex returns a list  of items from which I need to get only the date range. The list does not always have the date range at a specific index.

I tried converting the list into a string first and then extracting only the date range:

```py
possible_billing_periods = list(re.findall(r'Billing Period: (.*)|Billing period: (.*)|Billing Period (.*)|Billing period (.*)|period (.*)|period: (.*)', data))  
billing_period           = str(possible_billing_periods)

    for k in billing_period.split("\n"):
        if k != ['(A-Za-Z0-9)']:
            billing_period_2 = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", ' ', k) 

    print(possible_billing_periods)
```

***Output***: [('', '', '', '', 'Tel', ''), ('21-june-2018 - 25-September-2018', '', '', '', '', '')]

Expected result: `21-june-2018 25-September-2018`

Result got: `Tel 21 june 2018 25 September 2018`

Sample Data : 
28 August2018 Start Index: B1 0 
28 August 2018 Start Index: E1 0 
Billing Period: 21-june-2018 - 25-September-2018
Expected next reading: 25 December 2018

Comment: Can you also show us the sample `data` ?

Comment: We need to see a few lines of `data`

Comment: 28 August 2018 Start Index: B1 0 
28 August 2018 Start Index: E1 0 

Billing Period: 21-june-2018 - 25-September-2018 
Expected next reading: 25 December 2018

Comment: Are the dates you need always in the lines starting with `'Billing Period'`? Do you need regex to handle upper/lower cases?

Comment: The ('', '', '', '', 'Tel', '') in the output of your print statement shows that somewhere your data matches the fifth group in your regex.  That is the "|period (.*)|", where the .* matched "Tel".

Comment: I use OCR to pull this data from an image. The regex in first line of the code is just a sample. There are a lot of possible strings that can come along with the resultant list, which is the reason I am seeking for help from the community for a way to separate the date from the noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the data comes from a file, so it's easiest to process it line by line.  Here is pseudo code for a common way to process a file:

```
for each line in the file:
    if it is a line we care about:
        process the line
```

From the sample data, lines we care about begin with some variation of "Billing period:".  Here is a regular expression to find a line that starts with any of the variations in the sample code.  The ?x at the beginning is equivalent to the re.VERBOSE flag.  It tells the regex compiler to ignore whitespace so that I can spread out the parts of the regex and explain what's going on with some comments.

```
billing_period_re = re.compile(r"""\
   (?xi)            # ignorecase and verbose
   ^                # match at the begining of the string
   \s*
   (?:Billing)?     # optional Billing. (?: ...) means don't save the group
   \s*
   Period                      
   \s*
   :?               # optional colon
   \s*
   """)
```

Now if the billing period regex matches, then we need to find a date range.  Based on the sample data a date range is two dates separated by ' - '.  A date is a 1-2 digit day, a month name, and a 4 digit year separated by '-'.  Here is one way to build up a regex for a date range:

```
day   = r"\d{1,2}"
month = r"(?:january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)"
year  = r"\d{4}"
date = rf"{day}-{month}-{year}"

date_range_re = re.compile(rf"(?i)(?P<from>{date}) - (?P<to>{date})")
```

Putting it all together

```
# this could be for line in input_file:
for line in data.splitlines():

    # check if it's a billing period line
    linematch = billing_period_re.search(line)

    if linematch:

        # check if there is a date range
        date_range = date_range_re.search(line, linematch.end())

        if date_range:
            print(f"from: {date_range['from']} to: {date_range['to']}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your sample data, regex may not be the optimal way to retrieve the information (performance-wise).

Assuming the needed dates strings are always in lines starting with `'Billing Period'`, you could try something like this:

```
sample_data = """28 August2018 Start Index: B1 0
28 August 2018 Start Index: E1 0
Billing Period: 21-june-2018 - 25-September-2018
Expected next reading: 25 December 2018"""

billing_periods = list()
line_start = {'Billing':0, 'period':0, 'period:':0}

for line in sample_data.split('\n'):
    if line.split()[0] in line_start:
        billing_periods.append((line.split()[-3], line.split()[-1]))

print(billing_periods)
```

Output:

> [('21-june-2018', '25-September-2018')]

The dict `line_start` enables you to define a few possible line start characters.